# How to get element with python?

Tags: imputation

I have not any idea about how to implement it with such library and function. Anybody can give me some idea. Just some function name or idea or some helpful website url would be ok! Thanks!

I thinks it's different.

Comment: Your edits now make the question **extraordinarily** vague.

Comment: I am sorry. I have to edit it for some reason. Thanks everyone who replied me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How does linear regression map to your problem?**

- Given a matrix X, the rows may represent the samples, and the columns the variables.
- The column containing the `nunmpy.nan` value represents the target variable ("y"). The remaining columns represent the input variables (the x1, x2,...).
- The rows with observed values represent the training set, the rest represent the test set.

**The code**

Below is a code snippet that implements these points using your example matrix X.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

X = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, np.nan], [3, 6, 9]])

# Unknown rows (test examples), i.e. rows with a nan 
impute_rows = np.any(np.isnan(X), axis=1)

# Known rows (training examples), i.e. rows without a nan
full_rows = np.logical_not(impute_rows)

# Column acting as variable to predict
output_var = np.any(np.isnan(X), axis=0)
input_var  = np.logical_not(output_var)

# Check only one variable to predict
assert(np.sum(output_var)==1)

# Construct traing/test input/output
train_input  = X[np.ix_(full_rows, input_var)]
train_output = X[np.ix_(full_rows, output_var)] 
test_input = X[np.ix_(impute_rows, input_var)]

# Perform regression
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(train_input, train_output)
lr.predict(test_input)
```

*Note that using the specific X you provided represents an oversimplified case, where only two points are fitted, but these ideas should be applicable to larger matrices.*

*Also note there exist other more specialized methods to impute missing values from matrices (is understood in your question that this was an exercise). This specific method may be valid in cases where there is a linear relationship between the elements of the matrix (as is the case in your simplified example).*